# Is the universe expanding faster than we could catch up with it?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Like the title says, could we ever catch up with the expanding universe?

Comment: What do you mean "catch up"?

Comment: I guess theoretically physically

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. We are *in* the universe, how can we "catch up" to something we live in?

Comment: to the "edge" of the where it's expanding to

Comment: @Adsy There is no edge

Comment: @DavePhD How can something expand without an edge?

Comment: @Adsy picture either either a spherical surface expanding (closed universe), or an infinite plane expanding (flat universe) or and infinite saddle shape expanding (open universe).

Comment: @Adsy How could something which by definition encompasses everything have an edge?

Comment: of course there is an edge, it is called 'cosmological horizon'

Comment: and no, we cannot catch it, since it recedes at the speed of light

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rate of expansion, in terms of velocity relative to us, is proportional to distance from us according to [Hubble's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law).

So beyond a certain distance, the velocity is greater than the speed of light and we can not "catch up" to a region that is too distant.

(This is somewhat of an oversimplification, because the rate of expansion could accelerate or decelerate over time, but observations show accelerating expansion that will continue to accelerate).

Comment: It's worth noting that most of the volume of the visible universe is already beyond our "communication horizon": light that we emit today will never reach very distant galaxies as the expanding universe carries them away from us.

Comment: also note that light we emit right now will eventually reach galaxies that currently recede with $v_{\mathrm{rec}}=c$; while there are regions of space that we no langer can "catch up" to, these aren't simply the ones with recession velocities above $c$!